# Related to Graph daa structure

Tags: data-structures, graph

Could anyone please differentiate between implicit graph and explicit graph.Actually i tried to read Wikipedia page related to this topic but got confused.

Answer (score 0):

An explicit graph is an explicitly defined graph, where we know how many nodes and edges are present and which nodes have an edge between them.

An implicit graph is not explicitly defined, meaning we don't know about it's nodes and edges instead we are building the graph as we go in some process.
Which is very commonly in a backtrack search.

For example:  A simple backtrack for generating all subsets of a set {A, B, C}

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char elements[4]= "ABC";

void powerSet(int n, string subset){
    if(n < 0){
        cout<< subset <<endl;
        return;
    }

    powerSet(n-1, subset);
    powerSet(n-1, subset+ elements[n]);
}

int main(){
    powerSet(2, string(""));
}
```

We don't have any graph defined yet we're constructing and using the following tree:  (the recursion tree isn't the exact for the code above but it is very similar )

> ```
>        /       \
>       /         \
>      a           {}
>     /  \         / \
>    b    {}      b   {}
>   / \   / \    / \   /\
>  c  {}  c  {}  c {}  c {}
> abc ab ac  a  bc  b  c {empty}     :We get these subsets
> ```